# Rails 4.1 NameError in ChargesController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Nearly completed my app using stripe payments , I can process credit card details but when i want it show the receipt. I get error NameError in ChargesController#create. undefined local variable or method `product' for #

Charges_controller.rb

```
class ChargesController < ApplicationController

def create


  customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
    :email => params[:stripeEmail],
    :card  => params[:stripeToken]
  )

  charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
    :customer    => customer.id,
    :amount      => params[:amount],
    :description => product.full_description, # <---- error
    :currency    => 'gbp'
  )

  purchase = Purchase.create(email: params[:stripeEmail],
    card: params[:stripeToken], amount: product.price_in_cents,
    description: charge.description, currency: charge.currency,
    customer_id: customer.id, product_id: product.id, uuid: SecureRandom.uuid)

  redirect_to purchase


rescue Stripe::CardError => e
  flash[:error] = e.message
  redirect_to charges_path
end
end
```

product.rb

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  def full_description
    "#{self.title} #{self.subtitle}"
  end

  def price_in_cents
    (self.price * 100).to_i
  end
end
```

home.html.erb

```
<section id="content-details" class="row clearfix">
        <article id="details-article" class="col-sm-8">
            <h1 id="article-title"><%= @product.title %><span class="font-weight-light"><%= @product.title %></span></h1>
            <h3><small>By <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#author-modal"><%= @product.author %></a></small></h3>

           <%= raw @product.description %>
        </article>
        <aside id="details-aside" class="col-sm-4">
          <%= form_tag charges_path, id:'chargeForm' do %>
            <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script> 
              <%= hidden_field_tag 'stripeToken' %>
              <%= hidden_field_tag 'stripeEmail' %>
              <%= hidden_field_tag 'amount', @product.price_in_cents %>

             <button id='btn-buy' type='button' class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>I want this!</button>


            <script>

            var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
              key: '<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>',
              token: function(token, arg) {
                document.getElementById("stripeToken").value = token.id;
                document.getElementById("stripeEmail").value = token.email;
                document.getElementById("chargeForm").submit();
              }
            });
            document.getElementById('btn-buy').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                handler.open({
                  name: 'Open Cinema',
                  description: '<%= @product.title %> <%= @product.subtitle %> ($<%= @product.price %>)',
                  amount: document.getElementById("amount").value
                  });
    e.preventDefault();
   })
            </script>
            <% end %>


            <ul id="details-infobox" class="list-group">
              <li class="list-group-item active clearfix">DETAILS</li>
              <li class="list-group-item"><%= @product.details %></li>
              <li class="list-group-item clearfix">
                <span class="pull-left content-qualifier">Length</span>
                <span class="pull-right"><%= @product.length %></span>
              </li>
            </ul>
        </aside>
    </section>
</div>
<footer id="site-footer">
Made by <a href="http://onemonth.com" target="_blank">
<%= image_tag('chris.jpg', id: 'one-month-footer-logo', alt: 'Open cinema') %>
</footer>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="author-modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>About </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body clearfix">
            <div id="modal-left" class="pull-left">
                <p><strong><%= @product.author %></strong></p>

                <%= raw @product.description %>

            </div>
            <div id="modal-right" class="pull-right">
                <%= image_tag( @product.author_image_name, alt: @product.author) %>
            </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

adding fields to product.db

```
class AddingFieldsToProduct < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change

    add_column :products, :length, :string
    add_column :products, :author_description, :text
    add_column :products, :author_image_name, :string

  end
end
```

products table

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :subtitle
      t.string :author
      t.text :description
      t.string :sku
      t.decimal :price

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

have 3 html files 
one for home.html.erb , see above

and then purchases show.html.erb

```
section id="content-receipt" class="clearfix">
 <div id="receipt-container">
  <div class="dotmatrix left"></div>
   <div id="receipt-content">
   <h4 id="receipt-title">Thank You!</h4>
   <p><strong>RECEIPT</strong></p>
     <div id="receipt-details" class="row clearfix">
  <div class="col-sm-8 receipt-left">
<p><strong class="font-weight-heavy"><%= @product.title %>xxx</strong><br/> <span class="font-weight-light"><%= @product.subtitle %></span></p><%= @product.discription %>
    </div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
$<%= @product.price %>
 </div>
</div>
<a href="<%= @product.download_url %>"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">DOWNLOAD</button></a>
<footer id="receipt-footer">
<small>Your purchase is complete. We hope you enjoy it!</small>
</footer>
 </div>
<div class="dotmatrix right"></div>
 </div>
<div id="receipt-shadow"></div>
</section>
```

and then purchases_recipts.html.erb

```
<p>Thanks!</p>

Thanks for buying a ticket to the movie!

<a href="<%= @product.download_url %>"><butoon type="button"
  class="btn btn-sucess btn-xs">Download</button></a>
```

update

changed  amount to product.price_in_cents but getting same error

```
charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
    :customer    => customer.id,
    :amount      => product.price_in_cents,
    :description => product.full_description,
    :currency    => 'gbp'
```

)

Comment: `product` is not defined there. Why do you think that it should be defined?

Comment: Show your HTML form where `create` action is called from

Comment: have 3 html files , home , purchase_reciept and purchases show,html.erb

Comment: What's `product`? There's no `product`. You need a `product` if you want to reference it.

Comment: *have 3 html files* - But I still cannot find where `create` is called from. Please show your `routes.rb`

Answer (score 2):

Add @product.id as a hidden field to the form in show.html.erb

`<%= hidden_field_tag :product_id, @product.id %>`

And then in charges_controller.rb add:

```
product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
```

at the top of the #create method.

Answer (score 0):

There are typo's in your code that maybe preventing this from running. Look inside your "purchases_recipts.html.erb" file.

```
<a href="<%= @product.download_url %>"><butoon type="button"
  class="btn btn-sucess btn-xs">Download</button></a>
```

Should be:

```
<a href="<%= @product.download_url %>"><button type="button"
  class="btn btn-success btn-xs">Download</button></a>
```